# How to remove NaN in bokeh table

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using bokeh widgets table to show data, I use Dateformatter to format date, but null date is showing 'NaN/NaN/NaN' in Bokeh table, how to remove these NaN?

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()

c, conn = connection()

sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Database.SQLTable;"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sqlString, conn)
c.close()
conn.close()

#df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

cols = [
    TableColumn(field='ID', title='ID'),
    TableColumn(field='Activity_Title', title='Activity_Title'), 
    TableColumn(field='Originator', title='Originator'), 
    TableColumn(field='Country', title='Country'), 
    TableColumn(field='Activity_Date', title='Activity_Date', formatter=DateFormatter(format="%m/%d/%Y")), 
    TableColumn(field='record_insert_datetime', title='record_insert_datetime', formatter=DateFormatter(format="%m/%d/%Y"))
]     

data_table = DataTable(columns=cols, source=ColumnDataSource(df), fit_columns=True)
```

current result is showing:[image]

How to replace those "NaN/NaN/NaN" with empty string?

Answer (score 2):

As of bokeh version `2.2` there is `nan_format` in the [`DateFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.DateFormatter.nan_format).

Using `DateFormatter(nan_format="-")`gives:
[image]

[Github issue related to development](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/10375)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "fillna" function of DataFrame?

Here is example:

```
df["record_insert_datetime"].fillna("0/0/0", inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thank you Umesh, I just tried two ways: ```df["record_insert_datetime"].fillna("0/0/0", inplace = True)``` and ```df["record_insert_datetime"].fillna("00/00/0000", inplace = True)```, both are showing the same result "01/01/1970" not "NaN/NaN/NaN". but I want it to be empty, "01/01/1970" is not correct. Thank you

Comment: Great!. I applied it to my String. I expected an option in StringFormatter, but solved it this way.