# Bokeh DataTable not show in Flask

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I am developing a Flask web application to show data in a DataTable and also build interactive reports by Bokeh. My below code to show bokeh DataTable not work.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the Iris Data Set
iris_df = pd.read_csv("/data/iris.data", names=["Sepal Length", "Sepal Width", "Petal Length", "Petal Width", "Species"])

@app.route('/ShowIrisDataTable/')
def index():

    cols = [
        TableColumn(field='Sepal Length', title='Sepal Length'),
        TableColumn(field='Sepal Width', title='Sepal Width'), 
        TableColumn(field='Petal Length', title='Petal Length'), 
        TableColumn(field='Petal Width', title='Petal Width'), 
        TableColumn(field='Species', title='Species')
    ]     
    data_table = DataTable(columns=cols, source=ColumnDataSource(iris_df), fit_columns=True)

    script, div = components(data_table)        

    return render_template("iris_index5.html", script=script, div=div)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

my html file is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.16.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.16.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<H1>Iris Data Table version 5</H1>

{{ script|safe }}
{{ div|safe }}


</body>
</html>
```

My web application only shows heading "Iris Data Table version 5" but not the Bokeh DataTable also no error message.

I cannot figure where is wrong, appreciate your help.

Comment: Is 0.12.16 actually the version of Bokeh you have installed?

Comment: yes, I checked bokeh version.

Comment: Errors/messages in your browser JS console or network debug tab?

Comment: You might also try putting the table as the only item in some layout (e.g a `column`) I know there were versions where bare widgets were problematic (I thought they were before 0.12.16 but my memory may be off)

Comment: @bigreddot thank you, no error in browser, no error in sublime text py console as well. It is just not showing the table :(

Comment: i can't speculate more without a complete, minimal reproducer that can actually be run to investigate.

Comment: @brgreddot thank you for response, I just post code for IRIS data, you should be able to run code if you download IRIS data. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not including the JS/CSS files for tables. They are relatively large, so they are split into their own files so people that don't make use of tables don't have to pay the cost of loading the resources. Below is a working template. Note I have also updated the CDN urls to point at `cdn.bokeh.org`. The old locations will work indefinitely, but anyone who can should use the new locations.

```
<html>
<head>

<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.16.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.16.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.16.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.16.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<H1>Iris Data Table version 5</H1>

{{ script|safe }}
{{ div|safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great!!!! thank you so much, it is working!!! And sorry for the incorrect post as answer, sometimes just could not figure what to do.

Comment: I am wondering if you can help for my another ticket "How to remove NaN in bokeh table" -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654241/how-to-remove-nan-in-bokeh-table/58654297#58654297          Thank you very much.